# Wrong eigenvectors for the eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the following matrix:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

$A-\lambda I=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0\\0 & \lambda\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda & 1\\0 & 2-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$ and $determinant$ of that resulting matrix is $0$.

Then replacing $\lambda$s:

- $\lambda=1$: $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}y\\y\end{bmatrix}$. Then eigenvector $x_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$
- $\lambda=2$: $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-x+y\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Then eigenvector $x_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

But I understand that this is wrong and
$x_1$ for $\lambda=1$ should be $x_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and
$x_2$ for $\lambda=2$ should be $x_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

**What am I doing wrong?**

Please, go easy on me and thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace the eigenvalue $\lambda$, your equation is
$$(A-\lambda I) \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}= 
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

So, for instance, when $\lambda=1$ you get $y=0$ and for $\lambda=2$, $-x+y=0$.

Comment: Muchas gracias!